# Binding to the pixel value of a star-width column-definition

Tags: wpf, grid, size

I encounter a problem with the `Width` of a `ScrollViewer` in a column of a `Grid`.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding GridSplitter, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=5}"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding TableSize, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Auto}" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The `ScrollViewer` is in `Column[0]` but does not always stretch its `Width` to the `Width` of `Column[0]`. Therefore I would like to give it just a `Binding` to the Pixel-value of the `Width` of `ColumnDefintion[0]`.
Note that `ColumnDefinitions[0].Width.Value = 1` because it's defined as a Star-value.
Also note that binding to `ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth` gives a `Width` of 0.

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try to use HorizontalAlignment to Stretch?

Comment: @Maximus Yes. I found out that changing `ColumnDefintion[1]` to `TwoWay` is much better. No idea way - the setter  has no code.

Comment: On top of that it is important when both columns use Star sizes, that the `HorizontalAlignment` of the `GridSplitter` is set to `Center.`

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the `ActualWidth` value, like so:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=col1}"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" Name="col1"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: Like I said in the question this gives a Width of 0. I discovered that the binding properties are read *before* arrange and measure of the grid. That probably is the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: You are probably checking your `ActualWidth` property *before* the element has loaded. Check it in the window's `Loaded` event instead. However, binding using the method I demonstrated should automatically update the width of the column when the `ActualWidth` changes anyway, it's a dependency property.

Comment: `ActualWidth` of `ColumnDefintion` is just a double, only Max-Min-Width are DP's.